# Selenium, ChromeDriver start app

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-app, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to test a Chrome App with the help of WebDriver.

Normally when you want to directly start an App you pass the argument `--app-id` for e.g:

`/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app-id=olddgoefnehjeogjhpcpolcnnifnglkp`

Bur I'm not able to start my Chrome App with chromedriver:

I tried:

```
Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :args => ["--app-id=olddgoefnehjeogjhpcpolcnnifnglkp"]
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the Chrome Web Store
2. Install an App
3. Go to preferences --> Extensions
4. Enable Developer-Modus
5. Now you can see the App-Id for eg: ID: olddgoefnehjeogjhpcpolcnnifnglkp
6. Try to start WebDriver with this option:

   ```
   driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :args => ["--app-id=olddgoefnehjeogjhpcpolcnnifnglkp"]
   ```

Here is a list of arguments that should be valid for chromedriver:
http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found the related issue may help with you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557533/open-a-chrome-extension-through-selenium-webdriver