# chrome extension - how to invoke webDriver with chrome extension (not in a new tab)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to open webDriver with chrome extension (Modify header value) using below code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

but this code is opening the webDriver instance with the extention in another window can any one know how to invoke it with chrome extension not in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557533/open-a-chrome-extension-through-selenium-webdriver). Be noted that Selenium supports interaction with web view only. You can check this [tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/6-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium) on how to test your Chrome Extension with selenium. However, you can also use of [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) (Automation tool that make use of image recognition), to click the chrome add-on. After that add-on popup will be another browser window, so use switch window to perform actions on add-on popup. Hope this helps!