# How to launch Chrome Extension using Automation (Robot Framework, etc.)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, automation, robotframework

I need to launch a particular chrome extension in my automation. I am currently using Selenium with Java. But I am unable to launch my chrome extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a chrome extension through Selenium WebDriver using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557533/open-a-chrome-extension-through-selenium-webdriver-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly there are two approaches.

**1. install desired extension in runtime** - https://dev.to/razgandeanu/testing-chrome-extensions-with-selenium-491b

**2.** manualy install desired extension do existing browser profile and use the **existing profile in selenium**. Like this:

```
package packageName;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class WebdriverSetup {   
    public static String chromedriverPath = "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\selenium-tests\\GCH_driver\\chromedriver.exe";

    // my default profile folder
    public static String chromeProfilePath = "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";    

    public static WebDriver driver; 
    public static WebDriver startChromeWithCustomProfile() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        // loading Chrome with my existing profile instead of a temporary profile
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + chromeProfilePath);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }
    public static void shutdownChrome() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: One note is that in headless mode you cannot install extensions, that's a ChromeDriver limitation: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5