# Loading .crx into remote chrome Selenium python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to install my extension onto a remote machine with selenium.
I have found a few snippets of code which would make this possible, but i cannot figure out how to get it to work.

What i have tried so far is this:

```
desired_cap = {'browser': 'Chrome', 'browser_version': '50.0', 'os': 'Windows', 'os_version': '10', 'resolution': '1366x768'}

def officialv1():
    url= 'loginurl'
        chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chop.add_extension('./Shoppingbuddy_v5.4.2.crx')
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url, desired_capabilities=desired_cap, chrome_options=chop)
```

With `chrome_options=chop` out of place, because i do not know how to push this command to the remote browser aside with the `command_executor` and the `desired_capabilities` arguments.

I am stuck with telling my remote chrome to install the extension with the local file.
So how do i tell my remote and active chrome, to install an extension which is in my local script folder.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800689/running-selenium-webdriver-using-python-with-extensions-crx-files), which answers my question partially, but it does not tell me how to do it remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to add an extension with Chrome with a remote server:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension(r'C:\Downloads\Adblock-Plus_v1.11.crx')

capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
capabilities.update({'browser_version': '50.0', 'os': 'Windows', 'os_version': '10', 'resolution': '1366x768'})

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Note that it is preferable to set the `Log level` to `WARNING` to stop the server from writing the binary content of the extension in the log and console:

```
java -Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
```