# Selenium - Chrome Web Driver - Html Only, No Images

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing a lot of testing with the Chrome Web Driver within Selenium.  The problem is that every time I run it, it has to re-download all the site images which takes time.  It does not keep these images cached.

So I would like to set which files to render and which not too.  Obviously I want Javascript and CSS files to still download.  But I particularily want to turn off images.

Is this possible? If not, is there a way to enable caching?  So the next time I run the progran it can get the images from the local cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching from one session to another is not possible as far as I know.

However, it is possible to remove rendering the page if you run it headless.  This will load the page, but not render it (make it visible, load images).

You can use HTMLUnitDriver, which is the standard, but somewhat outdated, or you can use PhantomDriver, which has a more modern version of Javascript.

Comment: PhantonDriver seems to be a Javascript system.  However it looks like HTMLUnitDriver is what I am looking for.  I see it was modified this year, so there may still be hope.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to load the same chrome profile again, it should (may not) ensure that images & other similar things are cached.

Here is how to load a particular profile :

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=/path/to/profile/directory"));
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

A similar search on SO, gave this result - [Load Chrome Profile using Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver) you might bother to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, the caching issue was a 2nd prize for me but I marked the other answer as correct as it is what I was really after.

Answer (score 1):

**"You can use HTMLUnitDriver" >>> careful with this!**

Please note that since HTMLUnitDriver is not the same implementation as the real browser, you may or may not get the same results in both.
So if you start hitting weird issues, like running the test with Chrome passes but running the test with HTMLUnitDriver does not, consider just running your tests with the browser driver. I've heard of looong troubleshooting stories from colleagues and they had to give up on running their suites in headless mode (ie, using HTMLUnitDriver).

**NOTE: since I cannot leave a comment on the selected answer**, I am "forced" to leave it as an answer. If somebody can help me convert it in a comment, I will appreciate! thanks

Comment: any implementations for this?

Comment: @uzu what do you mean by "any implementations"?

Answer (score 0):

For caching images you would need something like squid or haproxy, and then proxy your selenium browser through it.

Comment: Thanks, but the first prize is actually to turn off images all together.