# WebDriver - "Keep Me Logged In"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am testing an application that requires login. Using SafariDriver when I click the "Keep Me Logged In" button every new SafariDriver instance that is created is automatically logged in as expected; but when I use FirefoxDriver or ChromeDriver I am asked for my credentials every time as if I've never logged to the site using that browser before (when I have both manually and using webdriver). Is there some setting I need to enable so FireFox and Chrome keep me logged in?

Comment: Do you have the clear cache and cookies after closing browser options checked in?

Comment: @Saifur I don't think so, when I quite a restart the browsers manually I am kept logged in. Where can I check these options please?

Comment: See [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox) for firefox. Chrome [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/1302XTQSUWM)

Comment: @Saifur Thanks, I check and both FireFox and Chrome are set to keep browser data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because WebDriver creates a new FireFox profile for every session. These profiles include caches/bookmarks/plugins etc. for more information refer to the [documentation](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_finding-your-profile-without-opening-firefox). FirefoxDirver allows you to start a FireFox with a specific profile. This can be done by using the following code:

```
FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile(new File("/Path/to/profile/directory"));
driver = new FirefoxDriver(ff);
```

I'll update the answer if I find the way to do this in chrome

Comment: Oh yes. I misunderstood your question. I thought you do not want the browsers to save cookies. Yes this is the right way

Comment: There seems to be some information on how to do it in chrome here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver I haven't had time to try it myself tough

Comment: for chrome, you do
`options.add_argument("user-data-dir" + profile_path)` you can have the profile path be a path to an empty directory and chrome will ask you to login only once.