# Selenium- Popup got blocked if I clicked Link using Javascript Executor in Chrome browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Problem Description - Upon clicking a link on the page, popup got blocked automatically.

```
   file = new File("tools/chromedriver.exe");
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
   caps.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
   caps.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

Environment used – Selenium WebDriver – 2.43.0 ChromeDriver, Windows 7

Note – it is working fine on Firefox & IE, this issue is happening on Chrome only.

Please assist on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Chrome Option to disable all popups for the site](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en)

- Open Chrome.
- Find a page that has pop-ups blocked for you.
- At the end of the address bar, click the pop-up blocker icon chrome op-up
  locked.
- Click the link for the pop-up window you'd like to see.
- To always see pop-ups for the site, select Always show pop-ups from [site]. 
  Once you have this set use the profile it is saved against to load for the test 
  Another option is to open the site and Shift F5 to do a [Cache Refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)
  [Load a Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver). The code below is C# and you haven't specified a language. Please see the links provided for Java examples

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
userDataPath = "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data";
options.AddArguments("user-data-dir=" + userDataPath);
options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver("pathToChromeDriver", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the chromeOption to allow pop-up as shown in below:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.popups", 1);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```