# local connection issue selenium web driver with chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
package Demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userProfile = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + userProfile);
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Abhishek.Dalakoti\\workspace\\HomeShopDemo\\Chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*input[@type='text']")).sendKeys("dell");
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when running the above. Has anyone solved this?

I've tried changing the versions of Selenium and ChromeDriver versions, but nothing worked.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot create default profile directory

(Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) 

(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 750 milliseconds

Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'HSNMM-AbhishekD', ip: '10.50.33.160', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
    at Demo.Demo.main(Demo.java:16)
```

Comment: check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Already tried it's not working.

Comment: try by adding this:
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");

Comment: already tried this way.

Comment: i think ur problem is in ur chrome profile path.

Comment: I think so, too. Does the folder exist? Do you have write access?

Comment: Yeah it is created and it is there.

Comment: If you have any doubt you can run the above code in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straightforward if you look at the [ChromeDriver source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver).

If an `user-data-dir` argument is passed, the application [will take that](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome_launcher.cc#148) to be the profile directory, and it will expect to be able to **create** a directory named `Default` within it. [If it fails](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/base/files/file_util_posix.cc#570) to create it (and all required parents) or gets an error, you'll [end up](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome_launcher.cc#809) with:

> cannot create default profile directory

So the solution is to ensure that what you pass to `user-data-dir` exists, is a directory, is writable, and (presumably) doesn't already contain a `Default` directory.