# How to access added plugins in webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have added a plugin in chrome but, how can i access it through webdriver

```
File addonpath = new File("path of .crx file");
ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
chrome.addExtensions(addonpath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chrome );
```

Comment: Please look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver and https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: what kind of extension you want to use?

Comment: This is internal plugin which we developed....because of company policy  cant share it

Comment: There’s multiple ways to interact with a plugin, but your question is too vague to give an answer that would match your needs.

Comment: OP, as others have said, you need to clarify what you need by "access" the plugin. We cannot help you "use" a plugin without knowing what it is.

Answer (score -2):

Hi please do it like below

```
public class ChromeProfileWithAddOn {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    // Add ChromeDriver-specific capabilities through ChromeOptions.
    // i have added this add on on chrome  = https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-converter/dmgnkfgleaamgbhhojkfijjmjmngokkb 
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");  
 ########paste the location of .crx file you get in step 6 here########
        options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Users\\###\\Desktop\\hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo.crx"));
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\eclipseProject\\###\\src\\com\\###\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    // call chrome driver
    driver.navigate().to("chrome-extension://ldlmdngominhfffemgnfpoifladkpple/RestClient.html");
How to get above url : 
1.open the mainfest.json file there you will find  "local_path":"RestClient.html"
2. make sure your extension is installed in chrome and then 
3. go to chrome://extensions/ (follow steps-3 and 4 below)
4. you will get an ID value as shown in the image just below step 4 copy that
5. now u can make your url as "chrome-extension://ID/local_path"
6. now open it in chrome browser
} }
```

Code will be as above but we have to follow Some basic steps :

**NOTE** : i am talking example of **Advanced REST client** for ** CHROME** url below : `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo`

Step 1 :

```
 `Please download or if in-case already present go to the extension's manifest.json file`
```

if you want to download the add-on on your local drive please follow like this :

a.> download this extension **https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin**

b.> install it (on top right hand side of the chrome browser a CRX button will appear)

c.> Now search **Advanced REST client** in the **chrome web Store** or simply copy and paste the link in the browser

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
```

d.> Click on the CRX image/button, you will get two options [image]

Select download as zip (save it at your preferred location).

e.> unzip it

f.> inside unzipped folder you will find **manifest.json** file

Step 2 :

```
Copy the location of mainfest.json file
```

Step 3 : go to Chrome browser and in the url please type

```
 chrome://extensions/
```

here all installed add on/extensions will be shown

Step 4 :

```
please check the Developer option
```

option for **Pack Extension** will be visible now

[image]

Step 5 :
Click Pack Extension and under Extension root directory:(First option) paste the location of **manifest.json** file.[image]

Step 6 : if u have followed everything as above u will get this [image]

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: I can able in to install @raj but how can i access during test execution

Comment: Hi please look at the update answer and its working.just follow step by step.

Comment: This seems to completely miss the OP's (vague) point: how does he "access" an already installed plugin? This seems to be going into laborious detail on how to install, and then obtain the plugin's own URL, which seems to be completely meaningless. You both need to clarify in advance what the requirement is.

Comment: @  Andrew Regan what i have tried to tell **1.**how to install a new extension/add-on on google chrome instance with selenium and **2.**then how to access that. And this is what question is "How to access added plugins in webdriver"

Comment: (1) He already knows how to; (2) Until OP clarifies what he means by "access" it's no good guessing that he wants that particular URL. Hopefully if he edits his post to clarify how he means to "use" the extension, you can tweak your answer to fit.