# opening chrome with selenium - weird behavior when opening it with my user

Tags: java, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

this code does not redirect me to Instagram. when i debug it i see the program just stuck on the "new chrome driver" row. but when i delete the row in the middle (add arguments) it doesnt stuck and does open instagram! didnt find any explanation for this. can someone help?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\gum\\Desktop\\intellijprojects\\Instagram\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/gum/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/food/");
```

Comment: Is there another instance of chrome running when this is ran?  As far as I can see you can't have two instances of chrome running the same profile.

Comment: No. the window opened by the driver is the only chrome window.

Comment: You looked at this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver-using-java