# How to disable "always open these types of links in the associated app" Chrome alert

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, protractor

While executing my Protractor tests in Chrome I'm getting an alert similar to below:

[image]

I want to accept it to be able to continue with my tests execution.

First I've tried with `browser.switchTo().alert().accept()` but it didn't work.

Then I google'd a bit and found the following solution:

```
chromeOptions: { 
      prefs: { 
        protocol_handler: { 
          excluded_schemes: { 
            "app": true 
          } 
        } 
      },
```

but it didn't work either.

I need to be able to accept that in order to execute remaining test steps.

Comment: try browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 10000);
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();

Comment: I've tried this, didn't work. I think Protractor doesn't recognize this pop-up as an alert.

Comment: because it is not an alert and looks like extension. try to add "--disable-extensions" to your chrome options

Comment: "--disable-extensions" didn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Protractor and please excuse me if there are any syntax errors. Following Chrome options should help in disabling the "Always open these type of links in the associated app" popup.

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  acceptInsecureCerts: true,

  'chromeoptions': {
        prefs: {
          'protocol_handler.excluded_schemes.XYZ': false,
        }
      }
},
```

Note: XYZ is a **protocol name** of your app (through which the link is being opened), which you can get it from "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" in registry editor

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found protocol name in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Extensions\windows.protocol`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **--disable-infobars** to the config file.

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-infobars']
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try `browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 1000);
browser.switchTo().alert().accept();` or  `browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});`

Comment: browser.switchTo().alert().accept(); was my first idea and it doesn't work.
 browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]); doesn't work either because the pop-up is not really a "standard" browser window; I can interact with it by clicking one of the buttons, but I'm unable to locate any elements inside it.