# How to disable “always open these types of links in the associated app” using a registry key

Tags: google-chrome, registry

I have created a custom registry to launch few Urls in IE browser from Chrome.I have used below code.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:IE Protocol"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:ie:=%% & call start iexplore -nosessionmerging -noframemerging %%url%%"
```

But i am getting a warning window as "always open these types of links in the associated app" before launching IE from chrome.

I am looking for the way to disable this warning window using chrome registry protocol handlers.

The below solutions is for selenium. But am looking similar kind of solution using Registry settings

[How to disable "always open these types of links in the associated app" Chrome alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124895/how-to-disable-always-open-these-types-of-links-in-the-associated-app-chrome-a)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you wanted a solution using registry keys to make "always open these types of links in the associated app" to disappear but I am providing a solution using Chrome preferences file.

Following line needs to be added in the Chrome Preferences file to disable the popup completely without being displayed when a link or exe is being launched.

```
"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"XYZ":false}}
```

Note: **XYZ** is a protocol name of your app (through which the link is being opened), which you can get it from "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" in registry editor