# Selenium chromedriver doesn't open an existing profile even when told to

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Recently I've been trying to get selenium webdriver to connect to an already existing profile. I've got the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 19")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'path\to\chromedriver.exe', options = options)
```

Now what this is supposed to do is launch an existing chrome user, which in my case I created just for this. But instead, it only launches a guest user. I've already tried it with the \Default user in which case it connects just fine, but instead it cannot navigate to any website. I'm appreciative of any help <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Load Chrome Profile using Selenium WebDriver using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver-using-java) your profile should be put in another option:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 19")
```

Comment: I have been looking for this. Lots of answers didnt help but this helped. Thanks a lot.