Can I launch chrome driver with only Address bar and title bar enabled?
I need to launch chrome selenium web driver (I'm using java Selenium) with only the address bar, title bar enabled. I am currently using the kiosk mode, but that hides the address bar and title bar as well. I need to be able to see the title of the website and the URL of the website - but block every other feature like downloads and dev tools.
I thought there might be flags I could pass to chrome to launch it in this specific way?

You can set up manualy a browser profile (including extensions, cookies, all you need) and use this dedicated profile in selenium. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver-using-java
